# get files of a directory

Tags: controllers, varien-io-file

I'd like to get a list of files stored in a sub directory of the /media directory in a controller.

I tried to use this one:

```
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $sub_dir . DS;
$files = scandir($dir);
```

But the array $files is empty.

I tried something like that:

```
$file = new Varien_Io_File();
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $sub_dir . DS;
$file->ls($dir);
```

Magento says *Unable to list current working directory*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scandir` should at least return the current `.` and parent `..` directory. Make sure the directory exists and check permissions. Are you sure `$files` is an array at all?

When using `Varien_Io_File`, the correct usage would be:

```
$file = new Varien_Io_File();
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $sub_dir . DS;
$file->open(array('path' => $dir));
$file->ls();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use DirectoryIterator, then it works. Here's my code snippet:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .  $sub_dir . DS . $category . DS);
$extensions = "jpg|jpeg|png";
$images = array();

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile() && stristr($extensions, $fileinfo->getExtension())) {
        array_push($images, substr($fileinfo->getPathname(),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])));
    }               
}

return $images;
```

Hope this help anyone who has the same problem :-)
Maybe it's not the "magento" way, but it works